# Remote connection via JMX seems to hang in visualVM

Tags: java, jmx, visualvm, jvisualvm, jboss-4.2.x

I'm trying to remotely profile a java application which runs on the JBoss 4.2.2.GA application server that uses the 32-bit version of Java 1.7.0_03 and, furthermore, is wrapped by Tanuki service wrapper, so as it can be deployed as a Windows service. This application runs on a server with the 64-bit version of Windows Server 2012 R2.

Before trying to add a JMX connection to this applications, I've done the following actions:

1. Ensured that the port 1098 is not used by another program, by issuing `netstat`.
2. Created an inbound rule for the port 1098 on the FW of the remote server, applicable to all types of networks.
3. Set the following parameters in the wrapper.conf file of the Tanuki wrapper in the remote server:

```
    wrapper.java.additional.3=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
    wrapper.java.additional.4=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
    wrapper.java.additional.5=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
    wrapper.java.additional.6=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1098
    wrapper.java.additional.7=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1098
    wrapper.java.additional.8=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=xx.yyy.zzz.www
```

Tanuki wrapper starts a JVM with the above parameters.

4. Created an outbound rule for visualVM in the FW of my personal PC (Windows 7 Professional, 64-bit). I doubt the necessity of this step, but the connection is not established even without this rule.

Then, I've unsuccessfully tried to add a JMX connection to `xxx.yyy.zzz.www:1098` (I also ticked the "Do not require SSL connection" option). **EDIT:** I'm waiting for the connection to be established for hours, but it seems to hang during the process.

What could be done wrong here?